# How to use modulo to find if one number is divisible by the second in python?

Tags: python, modulo

I am new to python and have been trying to solve questions I have found online, but I am stuck on one:

"Write a program which takes two integers as input. If the first is exactly divisible by the second (such as 10 and 5 or 24 and 8, but not 10 and 3 or 24 and 7) it outputs “Yes”, otherwise “No”, except when the second is zero, in which case it outputs “Cannot divide by zero”. Remember you can use the modulo operator (“%”) to find out whether one number is divisible by another."

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, this question might have been answered however as you can see in our site tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour this type of question is not valid here and is bound to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to check if the second number  is zero, if not then check for modulo
See below code:

```
first_number = int(input())
second_number = int(input())
if second_number == 0:
    print("Cannot divide by zero\n")
else:
    if first_number % second_number == 0:
        print('Yes\n')
    else:
        print('No\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `%` to check the remainder of two number. it will tell if value numerator is divisble by denominator ( when a%b ==0 ) or not (when a%b not 0). in another way you can use `/` and `//` operator like `a/b` this will give a `float` type integer (quotient)  and `iinteger` type eg `4/3 = 1.333 and 4//3=1` and then you can print `print(a/b==a//b)`, before that you need to check if denominator is 0 or not , if it is 0 then throw error.
Below is example of how to check whether a number is divsible or not

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

if b==0:
    print('Cannot divide by zero')
else:
    val = 'Yes' if a%b==0 else 'No'
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
first_number = int(input())
second_number = int(input())
print(not (first_number % second_number))
```

Comment: give error when second_number is 0

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator works by dividing the first number by the second, so it makes sense that you would get a zero division exception when you try it.

You can either test before to see if you would cause an error, or you could assume the user wont cause an error and handle the case when they do. "Ask forgiveness not permission" as the saying goes.

```py
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 2
>>> a % b
1
>>> a % b == 0
False
>>> c = 8
>>> c % b == 0
True
>>> d = 0
>>> c % d == 0
ZeroDivisionError: ...

>>> try:
...     if int(input("First:")) % int(input("Second:")) == 0:
...         print("yes")
...     else:
...         print("no")
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...         print("Second value was 0")
...
First: 2
Second: 0
Second value was 0
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code may help you:

```py
first_number = int(input())
second_number = int(input())
if first_number % second_number == 0:
     print('Yes')
else:
     print('No')
```

With the modulo you can find the remainder of the division of two numbers and then if it is zero you can conclude that they are dividable.
To handle `zero` situation you can use the below code:

```py
first_number = int(input())
second_number = int(input())
if second_number == 0:
     print('Cannot divide by zero')
elif first_number % second_number == 0:
     print('Yes')
else:
     print('No')
```

Comment: I downvoted since SO is not a homework service. Be responsible when answering question and don't encourage offloading homework or similar without any effort shown to SO.

Comment: I understand the situation but I wrote the answer and then just added the explanation to it to make it more complete.

Comment: You even didn't give me a second to complete it :)

Comment: @KlausD. I disagree with that, I think the proper way to resolve this is downvoting the question and flagging it.